# passing a std::ifstream to function as a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, ifstream

I am sorry for the beginner question, but I do not understand what is going wrong with the ifstream. Is it not possible to send it to a function like a pointer (see below)?

The idea is that as a side effect I want the ifstream to move on while the function is being called, hence trying to send it as a pointer.

```
  string ID, Title, Body;

  ifstream ifs(filename);   // std::string filename

  while(ifs.good()) {
     ID = findCell(ifs)
     Title = findCell(ifs)
     Body = findCell(ifs)  
  }
}
std::string findCell(ifstream *ifs)   // changed to &
{
    char c;
    bool isPreviousQuote;
    string str;
    while(ifs.good())
    {
        ifs.read(c, 1);   // error now shows up here

        if (c == "\n") {
           break;
        }
        str.push_back(c);
    } 
    return str;
}
```

The error is:

```
invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' 
to 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: To explain myself here, I am trying to work with double quotes here and do not find current solutions working.

Comment: I think what you really want is to pass the std::ifstream as a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: As my local guru says: "A reference `&` is just a pointer in disguise". What makes the difference in this case?

Comment: Because a reference is **not** a pointer in disguise and your local "guru" is wrong.

Comment: A reference gives you an address to an instance of the object so you don't have to check for a null pointer.  It's much safer.

Comment: References are much simplier to use and reason about. For instance. You're current code isn't working because you're not using the address of operator `&` when passing the stream to the function. This isnt necessary with a reference. Also, a reference can never be null, so you're less likely to make errors with them.

Comment: Sadly, the error remains after changing * to &...?

Comment: Assuming you changed `ifstream *ifs` to `ifstream& ifs`, the error is not the same error. Now you're error should be on the `read()` line because `c` isn't compatible with `char *`. See [`ifstream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read). You should be using [`c = ifs.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get), and even then, the loop structure is wrong. it should be checking the stream status *after* the get but *prior* to the vector push-back.

Comment: Weird enough my Qt told me that `ifs.get()` returns an `int_type` so I was searching for the `read()`.

Comment: @WhozCraig With checking the stream status you mean `ifs.good()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function takes a pointer to `std::ifstream` object:

```
std::string findCell(ifstream *ifs)
```

Pointers should be initialized using the address of a memory block that they will point to.
In this case an address of `ifs` retrieved with `&`:

```
Title = findCell(&ifs);
```

Yet even better since `findCell` function requires the existence of the `ifstream`, it is much cleaner and more reasonable to pass by reference:

```
std::string findCell(std::ifstream& ifs) { ... }
...
Title = findCell(ifs);
```

Comment: Or wait, no. It moved down to the within the cell part. To the `ifs.read(c, 1)` part.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation!

Comment: @Dualinity that will certainly also work (reading into an address of sufficient size). I.e. jmstokers comment.